# Iphone app wont run after upgrading to iOS 4.2

Tags: xcode, ios4

After installing Xcode 3.2.5 iOS 4.2 an app that was perfectly working stopped working.  I have seen that this has happened to others but cant understand how to solve it.

My questions are:
1. How can I know where it is crashing?
2. What can I do to better debug and pinpoint the problem.

Here is the call stack.

[image: Call Stack]

Tommy thanks for the answer. I have build and run and suggested but when it crashes it does not shows where it crashed. Also I added a breakpoint inside the method but it does not stops there. Any further ideas? Here is the code snippet.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
ApplicationData *appdata = [ApplicationData sharedInstance];
if(appdata.currentCategoryIndex >= 0) {
    Category *category = [appdata.categoryList objectAtIndex:appdata.currentCategoryIndex];
    if(category.records) {
        [lab_norecords setHidden:YES];
    } else {
        [lab_norecords setHidden:NO];
        return 0;
    }
    return [category.records count];
}
return 0;
```

}

[image]

Now I am getting this error:

[image]

I believe the source of the problem is here in the same subCategoryView:

```
- (id)init {
if([[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SubCategoryView" owner:self options:nil]) {
    //if(self = [super initWit])
    cellowner = [[TableCellOwner alloc] init];
    [listTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [listTableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [listTableView initialize];
}
return self;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the trace you've got, check out the second column. The most recent thing in your application was a call to SubCategoryView numberOfSectionsInTableView:, in the fourth row (the one numbered '3'). The triggered exception was NSRangeException, where you attempted to retrieved object 4294967295 from an array with 22 objects in it. 4294967295 is how -1 looks if you cast a signed 32bit number to an unsigned number, so for some reason you're doing something like:

```
NSInteger variable = -1;
[array objectAtIndex:variable];
```

Somewhere within SubCategoryView's numberOfSectionsInTableView. Best immediate guess: some change between 4.1 and 4.2 is causing whatever method you use to populate the table to come up with the wrong results.

To advance from here, make sure you're doing a debug build and launch with command+y (or go to Build, Build and Run - Breakpoints On). When your program crashes this time the debugging window should appear, showing you exactly the line your program throws an exception at and allowing you to inspect the state of all your program variables at that point. The debugger will also allow you to place breakpoints, step through your program one line at a time and all the other usual things.

Comment: @Tommy i have edited my post could you take a look to see if you can be of further help? I am stuck.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it; a next step would be to set a breakpoint at the start of the method and to step through. You can set breakpoints in Xcode by clicking in the left gutter of a source code editor view. What Xcode should have done when your program crashed after a command+y run was show the debugger view with the current stack trace in a pane in the top left. Look for the first thing in there that's in your code and click on it to see the line in your code. Then use the area in the top right to inspect state.

Comment: @Tommy. I have set a breakpoint at the beginning of the method but it does not stops there. It crashes before. What I did is I build and run from debugger. Please see the image.

Comment: I have able to solve the problem. Mainly what I did is init to 0 instead of -1. For some reason in the previous version to to iOS 4.2 that was working but not anymore. Still do not know the reason why.

Comment: That's good news, sorry I couldn't be more help. I think the contract on when the various table delegate methods will be called is a little vague. There was a bug in one of my programs eventually revealed becauseand things you wouldn't get until after viewWillAppear began coming before then but after viewDidLoad. That was before 4.2 though, so barely relevant.

Comment: @Tommy, now I am getting a new error. Please see if you have any recommendations. This is driving me nuts!!!

Comment: According to the description of the exception, at the top of your new screenshot, listTableView does not implement 'initialize'. So there's no way to process that message. If you're not getting a compiler warning, you've probably declared listTableView as type 'id' rather than its actual type, or declared initialize in the interface but failed to supply an implementation.

Comment: @Tommy, yes I got distracted with previous error and did not analyzed properly. This is done. Thanks for the help. ldj